# java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have an issue of Spring Webflux project. First I made 2 pojo model classes, User and Post.

**User.java**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder 
@Table("blog_user") 
public class User {
     
    @Id
    @Column("user_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column
    private String username;
 
    @Column
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
}
```

**Post.java**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    @Column("post_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column
    private String title;
  
    @Column
    private String body;
    
    @Column("user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

and relative repository interfaces

```
public interface UserReactiveMysqlRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Long> {
}

public interface PostReactiveMysqlRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Post, Long> {
}
```

I made the webflux handler class like below, which try to extract user from Mono and put the user value into post class.

```
@Component
public class PostHandler {
 
    @Autowired
    private PostReactiveMysqlRepository postRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserReactiveMysqlRepository userRepository;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> findAll(ServerRequest request) {
        Flux<Post> fluxPost = postRepository.findAll()
                .filter(p -> (p.getUser() == null))
                .map(p -> {
                    User u = userRepository.findById(p.getId()).block();  // This line throws Exception.
                    p.setUser(u);
                    return p;
                });
    
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(fluxPost, Post.class);
    }
```

But the block() api line throws the error messages.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.aaa.blog.wf.router.BlogWebFluxEndpointRouter$$Lambda$1434/0x00000008006ce410@7d628cef [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/route/post/all" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1710) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at com.aaa.blog.wf.handler.PostHandler.lambda$1(PostHandler.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsingWhen.java:345) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$WeakScalarSubscription.request(FluxConcatMap.java:479) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.request(FluxUsingWhen.java:319) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:138) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:138) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ChannelSendOperator$WriteBarrier.request(ChannelSendOperator.java:296) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.onSubscribe(MonoSendMany.java:254) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ChannelSendOperator$WriteBarrier.subscribe(ChannelSendOperator.java:358) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSource.subscribe(FluxSource.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8660) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany.subscribe(MonoSendMany.java:102) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
        at reactor.netty.FutureMono$FutureSubscription.operationComplete(FutureMono.java:196) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.trySuccess(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:48) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeSuccess(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:717) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:272) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.removeBytes(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:421) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:931) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:354) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:895) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1372) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:921) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:907) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:893) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:531) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:125) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:356) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:923) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:907) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:893) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:127) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:923) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:941) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1247) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569) ~[netty-transport-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.86.Final.jar:4.1.86.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

As you know the default web server of Spring WebFlux is netty. And the netty seems not to support `block()` api function. Some replies advise to change the web server to tomcat, But I think it can not be the correct solution. How can I extract the user class value from `Mono<User>`? Or does my code contain the wrong grammar?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `block` that is what the error is telling you. Generally if you are using `block` in a reactive pipeline you are doing it wrong and basically loose the reactive benefits. You should probably use `map` instead of `block` to have access to the user and place it in the post. That being said your code also looks wrong as getting the user with the id of the post doesn't look really right. It will also not return what you expect, it will onlyu return the posts that initially had no user attached, so it isn't really `findAll`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you inform me of the sample codes, plz?

Comment: Replace `block` with `map` it isn't harder than that.

Comment: @M.Deinum : you mean *flatMap* I think. But, I have the impression that you try to do JPA job manually. I think that solving the user relation should be delegated to JPA. Maybe you miss an annotation somewhere.

Comment: I always use code completion for `map`/`flatMap` I always get a headache with those ;). This isn't JPA, this is probably Spring Data R2DBC and not JPA (which wouldn't be reactive in anyway).

Comment: Yes! This issue is of spring webflux r2dbc. My question is map function needs comsumer api. Kindly inform me what consumer api should be the parameter of map function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking code is not allowed on reactive schedulers. You need to define a flow using reactive API ‘map/flatMap‘ and return it from your controller.

From what I see `PostReactiveMysqlRepository` is reactive and `userRepository.findById()` returns `Mono<User>` you can use

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> findAll(ServerRequest request) {
    Flux<Post> fluxPost = postRepository.findAll()
            .filter(p -> (p.getUser() == null))
            .flatMap(p -> 
                    userRepository.findById(p.getId()
                            .map(user -> {
                                p.setUser(user);
                                return p;
                            })
            );

    return ServerResponse.ok().body(fluxPost, Post.class);
}
```

The key points here are

- use `flatMap` instead of `map` in case operation is async (returns `Mono` or `Flux`)
- use `map` instead of `block` to complete the reactive flow